# Triangle height question dividing edge

Tags: geometry, triangles

In a right triangle ABC, with right angle at C, H is the foot of the height from C. Show that $\overline{CH}^2 =\overline{AH} · \overline{BH}$.

I really have no idea to do this.

Comment: Use similarities.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the $\angle BCH=\angle CAB$ and that $\angle CHB=\angle CHA$ as $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle. So we have that $$\triangle CHA \sim \triangle BHC$$
Since two angles are the same. So $$\frac{\overline{CH}}{\overline{AH}}=\frac{\overline{BH}}{\overline{CH}}$$ Thus we have $$\overline {CH}^2=\overline {AH} \times \overline {BH}$$

Comment: Why is angle bch the same as angle cab?